# How to cite different pages of the same book in IEEE using Mendeley reference manager?

Tags: citations, ieee

I do know that the same book should be mentioned only once in the citation list regardless of the number of different page sections or chapters being cited of that book. I also know that different page sections or chapters should be mentioned in the text. For example, [3, pp. 15–20] or [3, p. 65].

How to do this in Mendeley Reference Manager? I tried manually adding ''pp. 15–20'' or ''p. 65'', however I was unsurprised that it was removed after the order of citations was changed in the citation list.

I was able to find how to add page sections, but it doesn't show in the reference list nor in the text of the word document.